# Proving Ordering of Angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to prove $$\text {If}\ \angle P \lt \angle Q, \text & \ \angle Q \cong \angle R, \text{Then}\ \angle P \lt \angle R$$Which seems super basic and makes sense, but I got told that I'm under thinking the proof and that I need to think triangle congruences to get angle congruences to show the less than/ greater than.

Anyone got any advice for me?

Edit:

The down votes would be better had there also been a comment as to why. If you'd like me to prove that I've put effort into this problem already I could put up my work for the part right before this question where I proved, i think, that trichotomy holds with two angles P and Q. I'm just having more trouble on these angles then I did on the segments in the previous questions.

Comment: It's true for any real numbers $a,b,c$ in general: $(a<b,\, b=c)\,\Rightarrow\, a<c$.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having. It makes complete sense when you use anything: Numbers, Angles, Lengths, etc. It doesn't seem like it needs proof. It just makes sense.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is to draw 2 pictures representing the two givens, and then combine them to reflect the consequence.

Answer (score 0):

What it might be, is the fact that you left out measures. Be specific in proofs, instead of $\angle P < Q$, use $m\angle P < m\angle Q$, if two angles have equal measures, then they are congruent. Therefore $\angle P$ is congruent to $\angle Q$, and since $\angle Q$ is congruent to $\angle R$, by transitive property of inequality, $\angle P$ is congruent to $\angle R$.

Don't forget when you're saying one angle is greater or less than another angle, it is important that you don't just address the angles, but the measure of the angles. And this proof uses transitive property of inequality. Hopefully this helps. Peace!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with your statement, but this book I'm using never uses the $m\angle \text{P}$ instead it just uses $\angle \text{P}$

Comment: Maybe you have to switch mQ = mR before you state inequalities? Other than that, I have no idea... Is that the entire question? Maybe you skipped something.

Comment: It's important to give a formal proof. Write it all down in steps. State the given first, the. Step one, step two, and so forth.

Comment: The first part of the proof, exactly written says, Prove that trichotomy holds, i.e $\angle P \lt \angle Q$, $\angle P \cong \angle Q$, $\angle P \gt \angle Q$. Which I did. The next ones says only exactly what I asked in the question above. They are not always specific about what they mean when they ask.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it seems that no reference to measurement can be made, so I would assume a proof using Hilbert's axioms is the aim. For that, consider angles $\angle ABC < \angle DEF$ and $\angle DEF \cong \angle GHI$. By definition, there is a ray $\overrightarrow{EJ}$ between $\overrightarrow{ED}$ and $\overrightarrow{EF}$ so that $\angle ABC \cong \angle JEF$. As an intermediate step, you'd want to show that there exists a ray $\overrightarrow{HK}$ between $\overrightarrow{HG}$ and $\overrightarrow{HI}$ so that $\angle JEF \cong \angle KHI$. (For this, I'd probably use the Crossbar Theorem and congruent triangles.) Then, by transitivity of $\cong$, $\angle ABC \cong \angle KHI$. Therefore, $\angle ABC < \angle GHI$.